# C I/O Scanning and Printing w/ Sentinels

Tags: c, printing, io, scanf, sentinel

I have an input file with a bunch of numbers such as:

```
3 7 10 21 8 4 9 2
```

And I have written some code that will record the highest and lowest value:

```
#include<stdio.h>
   main(){
    int low;
    int high;
    int current;
    char c;
    scanf("%i", &low);
    scanf("%i", &high);
    while((c=getchar())!= '\n'){
     scanf("%i", &current);
     if(current < low){
       low = current;}
     else if(current > high){
       high = current;}
   }
  printf("High: %i   Low: %i \n",high,low);
  }
```

Now I would like to be able to remove the highest and lowest and print out the other numbers. My question is, would it be wise to try and tackle this problem using sentinel values? Make a print statement that loops and if sentinel value is hit it just prints nothing?

Comment: To better address this problem, need to state what to do about repeated values that are not a min/max, what to do about repeated values that are a min/max.  Does the printed order need to match input order?

Answer (score 1):

Process the list twice.  First looking for low/high.  Next time, print if not low/high.

Using `\n` as a signal to indicate end of input is a problem as `\n` is a white-space that `scanf("%i"...` quietly consumes.  Best to use `fgets()`

Its a good idea to check the result of `sscanf()`.

1st two numbers may not be in low/high order.

Use `"%n"` to track progress through `buffer`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
  int low = INT_MAX;
  int high = INT_MIN;
  int current;
  char buffer[1000];

  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  char *p = buffer;
  int n;
  while (sscanf(p, "%i%n", &current, &n) == 1) {
    if (current < low) {
      low = current;
    }
    if (current > high) {
      high = current;
    }
    p += n;
  }
  p = buffer;
  while (sscanf(p, "%i%n", &current, &n) == 1) {
    if ((current != low) && (current != high)) {
      printf("Other: %i\n", current);
    }
    p += n;
  }
printf("High: %i   Low: %i\n", high, low);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
   main(){
    int low;
    int high;
    int current;
    char c;
    scanf("%i", &low);
    scanf("%i", &high);

    int val;
     do {

      printf("Enter a number:");
     scanf("%d", &current);

     if(current < low){

       val=low;
       low=current;
       current=val;
       }
     else if(current > high){

       val=high;
       high=current;
       current=val;
       }

       printf("%i\n",current); //prints the value if it is in between

   }while((c=getch())!='\n');

  printf("High: %i   Low: %i \n",high,low);//can remove if it this is not required
}
```